# create a view with selected items

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, sandbox-solution

i'd like creating a view with items selected when i click on a ribbon action.
I'm abble to have the selected items but i'd like to know if there are a way to put this items in a particular view.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you want to create a view where only specific items from a list are shown?

if you can filter the item list according to specific entries this can easily be done in the view settings menu, or you can create an additional column and set that to a value that you can filter for, you don't even have to display that column in the view.

this created view can be made default or linked to in the menu so it can easily be accessed later on.

hope this helps :)